# What does CPIM stand for in the context of AAD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

While documenting some custom B2C policies I implemented, I noticed I have no idea if "CPIM" actually means. Despite searching, I could not find the answer. Is CPIM an acronym? What does it stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Customer and Partner Identity Management. We use this name on the inside to refer to AAD B2C.